# Cassandra 3.4 with two cluster is not working

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, java-8

I'm doing one POC on Cassandra 3.4 with JDK 8 and Spring, and in that I am running it on cluster mode, I have two hosts and I am expecting that if one host is down then another should work.
But it's not happening, may be I have done some mistake while defining options. Can anybody check once ?

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.PoolingOptions;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy;
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.TokenAwarePolicy;

public class CassandraConnectionManager {
    int concurrency = 50;
    int maxRequestsPerConnection = 128;
    int maxConnections = 10;
    int coreConnections = 5;
    int port = 7001;
    String hosts[];
    private Cluster cluster;
    private Session session;

    public CassandraConnectionManager(String hosts, String port, int maxConn, int coreConn) {
        this.maxConnections = maxConn;
        this.coreConnections = coreConn;
        this.port = Integer.parseInt(port);
        this.hosts = hosts.split(",");
        this.CassandraConnect();
    }

    public CassandraConnectionManager(String hosts) {
        this.maxConnections = concurrency / maxRequestsPerConnection + 1;
        this.hosts = hosts.split(",");
        this.CassandraConnect();
    }

    private void CassandraConnect() {
        PoolingOptions pools = new PoolingOptions();
        /*pools.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, coreConnections);
        pools.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, maxConnections);
        pools.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, coreConnections);
        pools.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, maxConnections);
        pools.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, concurrency);*/

        Cluster.Builder builder = new Cluster.Builder();
        builder.withPort(port);
        for (String host : hosts) {
            builder.addContactPoints(host);
        }
        //builder.addContactPoints(hosts);
        //builder.withPoolingOptions(pools);
        //builder.withSocketOptions(new SocketOptions().setTcpNoDelay(true));
        //builder.withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE);
        builder.withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.Builder().build()));

        //builder.withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(100L));

        this.cluster = builder.build();
        this.session = cluster.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return this.session;
    }

    /** Close cluster. */

    public void close() {
        cluster.close();
    }
}


public class CassandraDAO {

    private CassandraConnectionManager casConnManager;
    private Session casSession;
    private PreparedStatement insertIntoP1events;

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CassandraDAO.class);

    public CassandraDAO(CassandraConnectionManager casConnManager){
        this.casConnManager = casConnManager;
        this.casSession = casConnManager.getSession();
    }

    public void insert(Person book) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.append("INSERT INTO ").append("showcase.login_event")
          .append("(person_id, event_time, event_code,ip_address) ")
          .append("VALUES ('").append(book.getId()).append("', '")
          .append(book.getEvent_time()).append("', ")
          .append(book.getEV()).append(",'192.168.50.50');");

        String query = sb.toString();
        casSession.execute(query);
    }

}





public class TEST {
    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx ;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml");
        CassandraDAO casDAO = (CassandraDAO) context.getBean("casDao");
        for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
            Person p = new Person(i, "Ev 0", 24,"2017-12-12T00:00:00Z");
            try{
            casDAO.insert(p);
            System.out.println("Inserting .."+i);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting ..");
    }

}
```

Comment: In the Cassandra logs, are you seeing that the two nodes are aware of one another? You should see one instance report that the other is down if you take an instance offline.You can also issue a nodetool repair on one node from the command line to confirm that it reports the other node is unavailable.

Comment: What is the RF of your keyspace?  Also, if you're going to do a POC, use the most-recent version (3.10); not an early (buggy) 3.x version.